# range of interpolateAtOffset()'s offset parameter

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, vulkan, glsles

Both the GLSL 4.6 and GLSL ES 3.2 spec say:

> The range and granularity of offsets supported by this function [interpolateAtOffset] is implementation-dependent.

This seems too open-ended to be useful. How am I expected to know what will actually work across multiple vendors? Is there at least a minimum supported range specified somewhere in the standards? If not, is there something de-facto supported by the major vendors that I can rely on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Vulkan, [the 1.2 specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html) requires the range and granularity to be reported with `minInterpolationOffset`, `maxInterpolationOffset`, and `subPixelInterpolationOffsetBits`, where:

> The values `minInterpolationOffset` and `maxInterpolationOffset` describe the closed interval of supported interpolation offsets: [`minInterpolationOffset`, `maxInterpolationOffset`]. The ULP is determined by `subPixelInterpolationOffsetBits`. If `subPixelInterpolationOffsetBits` is 4, this provides increments of (1/24) = 0.0625, and thus the range of supported interpolation offsets would be [-0.5, 0.4375].

Based on the minimum values of these required by the specification, you can rely on at least [-0.5, 0.4375] being available if `sampleRateShading` is supported.

For OpenGL, [the 4.6 specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) says:

> The built-in function interpolateAtOffset will sample variables at a specified (*x*, *y*) offset relative to the center of the pixel. The range and granularity of offsets supported by this function is implementation-dependent. If either component of the specified offset is less than the value of `MIN_FRAGMENT_INTERPOLATION_OFFSET` or greater than the value of `MAX_FRAGMENT_INTERPOLATION_OFFSET`, the position used to interpolate the variable is undefined. Not all values of offset may be supported; x and y offsets may be rounded to fixed-point values with the number of fraction bits given by the value of the implementation-dependent constant `FRAGMENT_INTERPOLATION_OFFSET_BITS`.

The required minimums are the same as Vulkan.

Trying to search through PDFs is painful so I won't bother looking at the ES spec, I would assume it's the same.